# Adding an item to scala.collection.mutable.HashMap

Tags: scala

I tried to add an element to a Scala `HashMap`

```
val c2 = new collection.mutable.HashMap[String,Int]()
c2 += ("hh",1)
```

but the above gives me a compile error.

```
[error]  found   : String("hh")
[error]  required: (String, Int)
[error]   c2 += ("hh", 1)
[error]          ^
[error] /scalathing/Main.scala:5: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Int(1)
[error]  required: (String, Int)
[error]   c2 += ("hh", 1)
[error]                ^
[error] two errors found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed Sep 1, 2016 1:22:52 AM
```

The pair I'm adding seems to be of the correct type as demanded by the `HashMap`. Why do I get a compile error?

Comment: Or `c2 += ("hh" -> 1)`

Answer (score 5):

The `+=` operator is overloaded to work with variadic arguments. Therefore when the compiler sees `c2 += ("hh", 1)` it interprets that as two arguments being passed in, one of which is "hh" and the other of which is 1. You can fix that either by using the `->` operator, i.e. `c2 += ("hh" -> 1)` or enclosing the tuple in another series of parantheses, i.e. `c2 += (("hh, 1))`.

Slightly gory details below as requested in the comments.

As for how all this works, in the case of mutable collections such as `HashMap`, `+=` is simply an ordinary method called with operator syntax (i.e. spaces instead of a `.`) or ["infix notation"](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html) as the Scala community calls it, as any method in Scala can be. It is provided by the [`Growable`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0-M4/scala/collection/generic/Growable.html) trait which mutable collections mix in. You can see on the documentation for `Growable` both the single argument `+=` method and the variadic method. In other words the following code would have also worked.

```
c2.+=(("hh", 1))
```

*Not all `+=`s are created equal however*. `+=` commonly shows up in `var`s as well. Although it can be called with method syntax `.`, it's magic syntax sugar implemented directly by the Scala compiler. In particular any nonalphanumeric name followed by an `=` gets desugared. `x $NAME= y` becomes `x = x.$NAME(y)`. In this case `$NAME=` is variadic if and only if `$NAME` is variadic.

```
var i = 0
i += 1
i.+=(1) // Also compiles

case class SuperInt(raw: Int) {
  def &*&(x: SuperInt) = SuperInt(raw + x.raw)
}
var x = SuperInt(1)
x &*&= SuperInt(1) // This works
x.&*&=(SuperInt(1)) // As does this
x &*&= (SuperInt(1), SuperInt(1)) // Does not compile because &*& is not variadic
```

Comment: Good explanation of the failure, and the double parenthesis fix. Perhaps you can improve the answer by reminding that all operators are methods in scala. I almost forgot that when I looked at +=

Comment: @Samar added an explanation about `+=`.

Comment: Thank you. Learnt some totally new Scala stuff from your edit.